# Why to use model.add(conv2D) twice

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
#1st convolution layer
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])))
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size= (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#2nd convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

#3rd convolution layer
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
```

in the above code, I had a doubt that why to use model.add(Conv2D) twice in every layer. Is it do convolution with filters twice or it is necessary to add twice to do once.

Comment: Yes, to do convolution two times.

Comment: They sholdn't call that a "layer", that is a "block", a group of layers. It's interesting to separate these blocks to know that the images are being reduced with a pooling, but each of these blocks have 4 layers. 2 of these 4 are convolutional layers.

Comment: Whether it be equal number of filters on both the statements or may be different also and I don't understand y need to give 64 and 64. instead can i give 128 in a single step.