# why need to use conv2D(64) twice, instead it can be used as conv2D(128). Is both are sme or different

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, keras

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])))
model.add(Conv2D(64,kernel_size= (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
```

In the above code whether I can use con2D(128) instead of conv24(64) twice.

Comment: you have asked same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629476/why-to-use-model-addconv2d-twice). It would be worth reading how [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) works!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot, because both configurations do not represent the same functions, this pattern was introduced in the [VGG network paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1556), and it is used to increase the representation power of the network. Two layers with 3x3 filters are kind of equivalent to one layer with a 5x5 filter (through composition), it is not equivalent to adding the number of filters

In particular, if you had a convolutional layer with 128 filters, this is not the same to having two convolutional layers with 64 filters each, specially considering that there is a ReLU activation in between them, which makes behavior more non-linear.